# RHPAM / JBPM How to call a business process which is in different space in rhpam?

Tags: rest, jbpm, reusability, rhpam

Please help me in ways to access from one business process to other business process which is in different space.?

I have tried

1. By using reusable task
2. By using Rest Task

These methods havent worked for me. Please help me in any changes I should to ?